# Creating a new dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to build a dictionary in Python. However, all the examples that I see are instantiating a dictionary from a list, etc . ..

How do I create a new empty dictionary in Python?

Answer (score 764, accepted):

Call `dict` with no parameters

```
new_dict = dict()
```

or simply write

```
new_dict = {}
```

Comment: Is there any difference between dict() and {}? Or do people just prefer one over the other?

Comment: @ Matt Apparently CPython 2.7 dict() is slower (6 times slower?), See: http://doughellmann.com/2012/11/the-performance-impact-of-using-dict-instead-of-in-cpython-2-7-2.html In any case I am starting to prefer the constructor syntax anyways since I find it easier to type and move code between dicts and function calls.

Comment: @DavidWheaton Thanks for pointing this out!
Personally, I find `new_dict = dict()` slightly more readable, nonetheless if there is such a big difference in regards to performance... Would go for performance! ;)
(For those who are confused about Python and Cphython see: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17130986/4773274))

Comment: I confirm it's 3 times faster to use { } than dict() in python 3.x

Comment: Yeah, I get about 4 times faster in python 3.6 for `{}` over `dict()` and 5 times for `[]` over `list()`.

Comment: In the vast majority of cases, it doesn't matter if it takes six times longer, since that's still an unnoticeably small amount of time.

Comment: ```{}``` is faster because it cant be overwritten but ```dict()``` can be so there are some extra checks and lookups

Answer (score 271):

You can do this

```
x = {}
x['a'] = 1
```

Answer (score 36):

Knowing how to write a preset dictionary is useful to know as well:

```
cmap =  {'US':'USA','GB':'Great Britain'}

# Explicitly:
# -----------
def cxlate(country):
    try:
        ret = cmap[country]
    except KeyError:
        ret = '?'
    return ret

present = 'US' # this one is in the dict
missing = 'RU' # this one is not

print cxlate(present) # == USA
print cxlate(missing) # == ?

# or, much more simply as suggested below:

print cmap.get(present,'?') # == USA
print cmap.get(missing,'?') # == ?

# with country codes, you might prefer to return the original on failure:

print cmap.get(present,present) # == USA
print cmap.get(missing,missing) # == RU
```

Comment: Good point! But I think the bit with `cxlate` makes your answer seem too complicates. I'd just keep the initialization part. (`cxlate` itself is too complicated. You could just `return cmap.get(country, '?')`.)

Comment: Consider using https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict instead of writing a translate function or using .get() everywhere.

Comment: Perhaps I would, except that the documentation is absolutely opaque to me -- it's terrible. I have no idea what they're telling me to do, or why I should do it. And .get() seems to do exactly the right thing -- plus it's extremely flexible. I'm sure its a lack of understanding on my part. With that in mind, my questions are: why bother? What is saved here, easier here, faster here, etc.? Benefit is exactly what?

Comment: This appears useful, but a bit complicated for beginners

Answer (score 26):

```
>>> dict(a=2,b=4)
{'a': 2, 'b': 4}
```

Will add the value in the python dictionary.

Answer (score 20):

```
d = dict()
```

or

```
d = {}
```

or

```
import types
d = types.DictType.__new__(types.DictType, (), {})
```

Comment: What is the difference between `types.DictType.__new__(types.DictType, (), {})` and just `{}`

Comment: For anyone reading this: the last "solution" is a bit of a joke - you _can_ use it (in python 2.x at least - won't work in py3k), but no one in it's own mind would ever want to do so ;-)

Answer (score 13):

So there 2 ways to create a dict :

1. `my_dict = dict()`
2. `my_dict = {}`

But out of these two options `{}` is more efficient than `dict()` plus its readable.
[CHECK HERE](https://doughellmann.com/blog/2012/11/12/the-performance-impact-of-using-dict-instead-of-in-cpython-2-7-2/)

Comment: Why are you referring to python2.7? (in a quite old article: 2012-11-12, "The Performance Impact of Using dict() Instead of {} in CPython 2.7")

Comment: (7 yrs later) performances did not changed even in python 3.x.x

you can see it running a %timeit my_dict = {} vs %timeit my_dict = dict()

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> dict.fromkeys(['a','b','c'],[1,2,3])


{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 2, 3], 'c': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Comment: the question states that the dictionary should be a new empty instance

Comment: Please check the details in question. The question is how do I create a new empty dictionary in Python?

Answer (score 1):

I do not have enough reputation yet to be able comment, so I share this as an answer.

The link shared by @David Wheaton in his comment to the accepted answer is no longer valid as Doug Hellmann has migrated his site (source: https://doughellmann.com/posts/wordpress-to-hugo/).

Here is the updated link about "The Performance Impact of Using dict() Instead of {} in CPython 2.7": https://doughellmann.com/posts/the-performance-impact-of-using-dict-instead-of-in-cpython-2-7-2/