# In python I am trying to set an alarm for an action to happen

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python I want to set an alarm, because I want to print game over after 5 seconds. All I need is a timer. I know this is a stupid question, but I searched the website, and found no answer. Please help.

Comment: I think we are getting too cruel with instant downvoting. Legitimately, this is a hard thing to find for a newer Pythonista.

Comment: i lost three votes for another question so i had to delete it

Comment: people even wanted me to delete the question

Comment: Pls note that Mariba is 13 years old and studying Python after soccer. C'mon folks -- everyone started somewhere.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, it is true

Comment: Being 13 is no excuse for posting questions with no effort. The sympathy upvotes are ridiculous. If you want to be helpful at least edit if you think it can be made useful.

Comment: @Mariba, this is the internet and I am Batman, btw do you also do a bit of the ole Doogie Howser @bridgewaterinternalmedicine?

Comment: @Wooble: As I Google `python create timer` it does take a bit of parsing to separate the answers with 'sleep' vs the correct answer of using threading. It is hard when you are at a point of not even knowing where to start and one pointer makes all the difference. Look at answers of several years ago like [Creating a new dict in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424942/creating-a-new-dict-in-python) with 62 up votes. Are we saying this question is more lame than that one? I repeat my earlier comment -- I think the SO community has tipped in the direction of being too cruel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`threading.Timer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects) like  this:

```
from threading import Timer

def gameover():
    print "Game Over"

t = Timer(5.0, gameover)
t.start()
```