# How to create a dictionary python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

How would I approach this problem, I am to create a dictionary, where the name of the individual is a key and the values are a tuple made of list of marks(out of 10) and a list of Grade.

So, I have in a text file:

Josh

```
8  A
8  A
6  C
7  B
9  A
```

Pablo

```
7  A
9  B  
8  A
9  B
9  B
```

output of that should be `{Josh:([8,8,6,7,9],['A','A','C','B','A']), Pablo:([7,9,8,9,9],['A','B','A','B','B'])}`

This is what i have so far:

def course_grading(student_file):

```
f = open('student.txt','r')

for line in f:
   new_line = line.strip('\n').split()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424942/creating-a-new-dict-in-python

Comment: What did you try to implement this? Which programming problems have you met during the implementation?

Comment: I tried to split it at the white space using .split('/t') but i dont know how to create a tuple of two list with first list of marks and second of grades

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According your question and your comment, I assume you have no problem with the text and input. So the point is how to split up mark and grade?

You can use `zip()` to do this

```
# This is an example for Josh, assuming you already have list call lines,
# lines = [(mark1, grad1), (mark2, grade2)......]
marks, grades = zip(*lines) # marks is a tuple of marks, grades is a tuple of grades.
```

There you go

By the way, the `split()` function will automatically strip `'\n'`

Comment: I have a question though, In a text file, how would I go about distinguishing a line with the students name from a line with students marks and grades?

Comment: @AlexRayo If you are expecting 'Josh' or 'Pablo', just add an `if` statement, otherwise, you could use 'if ord(line[0]) > 57 or ord(line[0]) < 48`  it returns true if the first character is not a digit. `ord()` is a built-in function to see ASCII code of a character