# Python to print value after colon

Tags: python, python-2.7

my command prints following output:

```
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Producing details for server state
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------

  power:ok
  fault:none
  state:assigned
  load:normal
```

I read the python Dictionary documentation:

```
myCat = {'size': 'fat', 'color': 'gray', 'disposition': 'loud'}
myCat['size']
output: fat
```

Like python Dictionary. How do I print power state, load

so what  I want to here is,  i have  to  redirect output file to like this:

Note: the command line output lines are random (length of file output is not constant)

```
serverstate = {'powerstate': 'ok', 'load': 'normal'}
```

so that I will print serverstate['powerstate']. I will get the value.

Please advise. If i am in wrong track.

Comment: normal has to be in quotations

Comment: sorry typo and added in quotes

Comment: If you want to add values to a dictionary dynamically : 
See this : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424942/creating-a-new-dict-in-python
followed by : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024847/add-new-keys-to-a-dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "my command prints following output", I assume you mean that you have an executable or something similar, which is unrelated to your Python script, which prints that output when you run it. Let's call it `check_server_state.exe`.

You can use `subprocess.check_output` to get the output of an executable into a string. Then you can iterate through the lines of that string and extract the key-value pairs.

```
import subprocess
s = subprocess.check_output("check_server_state.exe") #or whatever the actual name is
d = {}
for line in s.split("\n"):
    if ":" not in line:
        continue
    key, value = line.strip().split(":", 1)
    d[key] = value

print(d)
print(d["power"])
```

Result:

```
{'load': 'normal', 'fault': 'none', 'state': 'assigned', 'power': 'ok'}
ok
```

Comment: Hi Kevin,   Thanks a lot. it is working. but could you please explain what these two lines will do. key, value = line.strip().split(":", 1)
            d[key] = value