# How to create a new typing.Dict[str,str] and add items to it

Tags: python, dictionary, strong-typing

There is a great [Q/A here already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424942/creating-a-new-dict-in-python) for creating an *untyped* dictionary in python. I'm struggling to figure out how to create a *typed* dictionary and then add things to it.

An example of what I am trying to do would be...

```
return_value = Dict[str,str]
for item in some_other_list:
  if item.property1 > 9:
    return_value.update(item.name, "d'oh")
return return_value
```

... but this gets me an error of `descriptor 'update' requires a 'dict' object but received a 'str'`

I've tried a few other permutations of the above declaration

```
return_value:Dict[str,str] = None
```

errors with `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'`. And trying

```
return_value:Dict[str,str] = dict()
```

or

```
return_value:Dict[str,str] = {}
```

both error with `update expected at most 1 arguments, got 2`.  I dont know what is needed here to create an empty typed dictionary like I would in c# (`var d = new Dictionary<string, string>();`). I would rather not eschew type safety if possible. Can someone point out what I'm missing or doing incorrectly?

Comment: `return_value` isn't a `dict`; it's an object that represents the *type* of a `dict`. The things you import from `typing` are *only* for type hints, not actual values.

Comment: Note, type annotations **do not give you type safety**. There is no "typed dict" in Python, not built-in anyway. Annotations are for documentation or by use from third-party static time type-checkers, like `mypy`.

Comment: Also, assign a single key-value pair in a `dict`, you do `my_dict[key] = value`. `.update` takes *another mapping*, e.g. another dict, and updates the key-value pairs in the mapping you pass as an argument. So you *could* do `my_dict.update({key:value})` but that is rather wasteful for a single item(creating a completely unnecessary intermediate dict object). Alternatively, you can pass keyword arguments to `.update`, like so: `my_dict.update(foo='bar', baz='bing')` which sometimes is nice from a readability perspective

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The last 2 ones are the right usage of `Dict`, but you updated the dictionary with incorrect syntax inside the for loop.

```
return_value: Dict[str, str] = dict()
for item in some_other_list:
    if item.property1 > 9:
        return_value[item.name] = "d'oh"
return return_value
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out about 15 minutes after posting. It only took me a few hours to get to that point =/.  The  examples for `Dict[]` that I could find had `.update(key,value)`.

Answer (score 3):

Things like `Dict` aren't intended to be used at runtime; they are objects that represent types used for static type analysis. If you want a dict, you have to use

```
return_value = dict()
```

You can't use `Dict` to create an object with a restricted runtime type.

Comment: or more idiomatically, `{}` ;)

Comment: Just wanted to emphasize that `dict` and `Dict` are different :)

Comment: in the same vein, would lists be more commonly specified as `()`  instead of `list()`?

Comment: `()` is the empty tuple; `[]` is the empty list. Using the literals is more efficient, as no name lookup is required.